# how to capturefrom sony DCR-SR45 to computer in .avi format

Tags: windows-xp

i lost of problem in editting. so, please tel me how to capture in computer in .avi format and tel me rewuire hardware and software.

Answer (score 2):

well, if the camera and the pc have firewire ports, its a matter of simply plugging them together with a 4 to 4 pin or 4 to 6 pin firewire cable and letting windows import it. You can probably convert between formats with some flavour of ffmpeg, such as [winff](http://winff.org/html_new/) and do basic cropping and editing with something like [virtualdub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)

Comment: The fact you understood what the question was asking is worthy of an up-vote in itself.

Comment: I own a similar camera from ages ago ;p